# wp7 which control is used for the PhoneNumberChooserTask

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to develop a similar grid to the one for searching phone numbers. See sample picture below.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `LongListSelector` from the [Silverlight Toolkit for WP7] to achieve a similar UI. There's a great couple of posts on [WindowsPhoneGeek.com](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api) that cover it in detail.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I also came across this one https://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2010/11/02/hail-to-the-swiss-army-knife-of-silverlight-windows-phone-apps-longlistselector.aspx

Comment: meant to say related link. tx